# Change C++ compiler from Ubuntu to MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, ubuntu, clion

I have course in C++ this semester at the university.
They ask us to use Ubuntu for the semester tasks because of compiling reasons.

I have Mac OS. Can I change the compiler to be the same as Ubuntu's?

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have a single compiler, although it's likely that your instructor intends for people to use gcc. I would ask them for more details about what exactly they mean about "compiling reasons", because right now the best anyone can do is start listing which compilers are available on which versions of Mac OS and have no idea if that's an actual answer to your question.

Comment: You could run ubuntu on a docker image on mac or you can run a virtual machine on your mac that has ubuntu installed.

Comment: But if you write standard compliant code it will make little difference. Just make sure you are using the same version of C++ as your teacher.

Comment: The most compliant and fail-safe method would be to load a VM with the same version of Ubuntu they will use for grading. I can say that I've run into these "compiling reasons" this semester. They are far and few between, though. I had Windows users use WSL Debian, and mac users just install XCode CLT. So I have g++ and clang++, both compiling to their default C++14. The issues arise from students doing stupid stuff, like not including what they use. g++ --> clang++/msvc has been the sole culprit since libstdc++ likes to bring in all kinds of libraries for you.

Comment: At the end of the day, this is barely an issue, especially for an Intro-level course. I don't recommend Docker on a Mac unless you're fine giving up ~50GB of storage for a ~1GB docker image.

Comment: The language is called C++, not "cpp". I've edited your question.

Comment: The answer to your question is easily found by asking your professor or his TA.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with MacOS, but as far as I'm concerned, when you install `XCode` it automatically installs `g++`, which is a compiler you can use on Linux and Windows (with mingw).
Also, if you don't want to install XCode, you can get `gcc` / `g++` through `homebrew`: https://brew.sh/

Another alternative would be `clang` / `clang++`.